# Converted a grayscale image to binary, but when writing the image I don't get a binary image

Tags: matlab, binary, grayscale

I have a `grayscale` image which I have converted to `binary`. But, when I `imwrite` it, I don't get a `binary` image. That is, an image with two values (i.e; 0,1), why is that?

Answer (score 1):

As per `imwrite`'s doc:

```
If the input array is of class double, and the image is a grayscale
or RGB color image, IMWRITE assumes the dynamic range is [0,1] and
automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as
8-bit values.
```

That could be the issue.

Comment: From the doc I would guess casting as `logical` should to the trick. Check http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html Note that using `im2bw` you should already get a logical image directly.

Answer (score 0):

well let's see how to turn an image to BW and save it, I hope you can find missing point:

1st read an image:

```
im = imread('img_name.jpg');
```

2nd convert it to BW:

```
bw = im2bw(im, graythresh(im));
```

3rd save it:

```
imwrite(bw, 'binary_image_name.jpg', 'jpg');
```

I guess, you miss image format at second argument of 'imwrite' function ('binary_image_name.jpg')

Comment: I did as you mentioned, but didn't get the expected result

Comment: well I check it again with another image and It's working! so I think you may miss sth before conversion! plz, explain more about what are you doing?